# How can I measure TCP/IP throughput on beaglebone black?

Tags: c, linux, debian, tcp, beagleboneblack

I'm using beaglebone black. The operating system is Debian GNU/Linux 7.7.
I'm using C language to run a server and client using TCP/IP.

This is the code I am using for server:

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
 while(1)
 {
 bzero(buffer,256);
 n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
 if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
 printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
 n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
 if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
 }
 close(newsockfd);
 close(sockfd);
 return 0; 
}
```

And this is the code I am using for client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    while(1)
    {
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I use `gcc` to compile the c codes. And then I run them like this:

on the server side:
`./server 32000`

On the client side:
`./client [IP address of server] 32000`

And messages are transferred from client to server. Now, how can I measure the throughput? I have installed `iperf` but I don't know how I can use it when server and client are running. Because when they are running I can only transfer messages, I can't type any other command.

The Ethernet of beaglebone black is 10/100M. How can I know the throughput of the Ethernet for the current communiation?

Comment: Are the client and server running on the same machine?

Comment: I've tried it both for same machine and separate machines (both on linux)

Comment: Are you trying to measure the throughput for this particular TCP session or TCP throughput in general.

Comment: both. I need to know an estimate of the throughput to decide whether it is suitable for my purpose

Comment: Throughput is measured in bits/second. So you need to send data continuously until a specified time(say 10 secs). Count number of bytes successfully sent/received in your client code(let say that is bytes_count). Calculate throughput as bytes_count/10.

Comment: Your code is not sending data continuously and this is not the way throughput is measured.
PS: This is called goodput not throughput.

Comment: throughput/goodput = (bytes_count*8)/time

Answer (score 0):

You can directly install and use [netperf](http://www.netperf.org/netperf/) which is a bench-marking tool.
You wont need to write a server and client separately.